# How can I open a new window/page using Xamarin for an Android App?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am setting up a new Android App. I failed by trying to open a new window/page when I click on one button.

I know how it works when using WPFs but I am new to Xamarin. What I want is this:
`Window w1 = new Window()`;

So when I click on this one button, a specific window/page will appear.

I tried following:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);  
button.Click += delegate {  StartActivity(typeof(settings)) };
```

I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Please update your post to include code you have tried, what isn't working and expected output. Usually you would use something like: `App.Navigation.PushAsync` to push a new page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android-multiscreen/

Comment: The comment of @Jason is right, but it gives two links. To be more specific, your answer can be found at the Quick Start page [Hello Android Multiscreen Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android-multiscreen/hello-android-multiscreen-quickstart?pivots=windows). More indepth can be found at the other link.

Comment: To be clear theres a difference between a page/window.. Which is it?

Comment: What is the difference? I can't tell, sorry. What I want is something like a new window in WPF, but just for Android

Comment: @user11064240 Android supports Multi-Window is that is what you are looking for, review the official docs for what it actually is: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window Otherwise, starting a "new" page of content (an Activity) is typically done via `StartActivity` or changing sections of an existing page is done via the FragmentManager.

Comment: Is the `settings` in your code an Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood you want to start another activity on a button click in android

You can do it like this:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);  
button.Click += delegate {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YOURSECONDACTIVITYHERE));
    startActivity(intent);
};
```

Note: this isn't a cross-platform code it's just for Android. I suggest you look up tutorials and write your code in Xamarin shared project files. In case you want to extend your project for other systems later.